# os.system working with lcov --remove but subprocess.call is not

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, os.system, lcov

I'm using lcov, I want to exclude some files/directories from my coverage reports.

When I use os.system():

```py
os.system("lcov --remove  build/unit_test_coverage.info \'*test*\' \'*mock*\' -o build/unit_test_coverage.info")
```

It excludes the files/directories as I expect.

But when I use subprocess.call() like this:

```py
subprocess.call(["lcov", "--remove", "build/unit_test_coverage.info", "\'*test*\'", "\'*mock*\'", "-o", "build/unit_test_coverage.info"])
```

The files/directories are not exluded.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.call` does not use a shell by default so you do not need to escape or protect "*".  Do it like this:

```py
subprocess.call(["lcov", "--remove", "build/unit_test_coverage.info", "*test*", "*mock*", "-o", "build/unit_test_coverage.info"])
```

The docs for [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) say to look at the docs for [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to see how the arguments work.  There it says that the shell is only used if you also specify `shell=True` and give it a string as first argument.  There is also a "note" block there explaining this stuff.